# how to build model for this json that has many keys

Tags: flutter, dart

strong textIt contains a lot of data for many countries, and each time the key symbolizes another country. How can I build a model for this json?

How can I deal with so many countries and display them?

1. This is my json.
2. So is this, but now follows a json result:

```
{
 "af": {
   "name": "Afghanistan",
   "official_name": "Islamic Republic of Afghanistan",
   "topLevelDomain": [
     ".af"
   ],
   "alpha2Code": "AF",
   "alpha3Code": "AFG",
   "cioc": "AFG",
   "numericCode": "004",
   "callingCode": "+93",
   "capital": "Kabul",
   "altSpellings": [
     "AF",
     "Afġānistān"
   ],
   "region": "Asia",
   "subregion": "Southern Asia",
   "population": 2837743,
   "latLng": {
     "country": [
       33,
       65
     ],
     "capital": [
       34.52,
       69.18
     ]
   },
   "demonyms": {
     "eng": {
       "f": "Afghan",
       "m": "Afghan"
     },
     "fra": {
       "f": "Afghane",
       "m": "Afghan"
     }
   },
   "area": 652230,
   "gini": "Not Available",
   "timezones": [
     "UTC+04:30"
   ],
   "borders": [
     "IRN",
     "PAK",
     "TKM",
     "UZB",
     "TJK",
     "CHN"
   ],
   "nativeNames": {
     "prs": {
       "official": "جمهوری اسلامی افغانستان",
       "common": "افغانستان"
     },
     "pus": {
       "official": "د افغانستان اسلامي جمهوریت",
       "common": "افغانستان"
     },
     "tuk": {
       "official": "Owganystan Yslam Respublikasy",
       "common": "Owganystan"
     }
   },
   "currencies": {
     "AFN": {
       "name": "Afghan afghani",
       "symbol": "؋"
     }
   },
   "languages": {
     "prs": "Dari",
     "pus": "Pashto",
     "tuk": "Turkmen"
   },
   "translations": {
     "ara": "أفغانستان",
     "ces": "Afghánistán",
     "cym": "Affganistan",
     "deu": "Afghanistan",
     "est": "Afganistan",
     "fin": "Afganistan",
     "fra": "Afghanistan",
     "hrv": "Afganistan",
     "hun": "Afganisztán",
     "ita": "Afghanistan",
     "jpn": "アフガニスタン",
     "kor": "아프가니스탄",
     "nld": "Afghanistan",
     "per": "افغانستان",
     "pol": "Afganistan",
     "por": "Afeganistão",
     "rus": "Афганистан",
     "slk": "Afganistan",
     "spa": "Afganistán",
     "swe": "Afghanistan",
     "urd": "افغانستان",
     "zho": "阿富汗"
   },
   "flag": {
     "small": "https://flagcdn.com/24x18/af.png",
     "medium": "https://flagcdn.com/96x72/af.png",
     "large": "https://flagcdn.com/256x192/af.png"
   },
   "regionalBlocs": [
     {
       "acronym": "SAARC",
       "name": "South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation"
     }
   ]
 },
 "sd": {
   "name": "Sudan",
   "official_name": "Republic of the Sudan",
   "topLevelDomain": [
     ".sd"
   ],
   "alpha2Code": "SD",
   "alpha3Code": "SDN",
   "cioc": "SUD",
   "numericCode": "729",
   "callingCode": "+249",
   "capital": "Khartoum",
   "altSpellings": [
     "SD",
     "Republic of the Sudan",
     "Jumhūrīyat as-Sūdān"
   ],
   "region": "Africa",
   "subregion": "Northern Africa",
   "population": 43849269,
   "latLng": {
     "country": [
       15,
       30
     ],
     "capital": [
       15.6,
       32.53
     ]
   },
   "demonyms": {
     "eng": {
       "f": "Sudanese",
       "m": "Sudanese"
     },
     "fra": {
       "f": "Soudanaise",
       "m": "Soudanais"
     }
   },
   "area": 1886068,
   "gini": {
     "2014": 34.2
   },
   "timezones": [
     "UTC+03:00"
   ],
   "borders": [
     "CAF",
     "TCD",
     "EGY",
     "ERI",
     "ETH",
     "LBY",
     "SSD"
   ],
   "nativeNames": {
     "ara": {
       "official": "جمهورية السودان",
       "common": "السودان"
     },
     "eng": {
       "official": "Republic of the Sudan",
       "common": "Sudan"
     }
   },
   "currencies": {
     "SDG": {
       "name": "Sudanese pound"
     }
   },
   "languages": {
     "ara": "Arabic",
     "eng": "English"
   },
   "translations": {
     "ara": "السودان",
     "ces": "Súdán",
     "cym": "Sudan",
     "deu": "Sudan",
     "est": "Sudaan",
     "fin": "Sudan",
     "fra": "Soudan",
     "hrv": "Sudan",
     "hun": "Szudán",
     "ita": "Sudan",
     "jpn": "スーダン",
     "kor": "수단",
     "nld": "Soedan",
     "per": "سودان",
     "pol": "Sudan",
     "por": "Sudão",
     "rus": "Судан",
     "slk": "Sudán",
     "spa": "Sudán",
     "swe": "Sudan",
     "urd": "سودان",
     "zho": "苏丹"
   },
   "flag": {
     "small": "https://flagcdn.com/24x18/sd.png",
     "medium": "https://flagcdn.com/96x72/sd.png",
     "large": "https://flagcdn.com/256x192/sd.png"
   },
   "regionalBlocs": [
     {
       "acronym": "AU",
       "name": "African Union",
       "otherNames": [
         "الاتحاد الأفريقي",
         "Union africaine",
         "União Africana",
         "Unión Africana",
         "Umoja wa Afrika"
       ]
     },
     {
       "acronym": "AL",
       "name": "Arab League",
       "otherNames": [
         "جامعة الدول العربية",
         "Jāmiʻat ad-Duwal al-ʻArabīyah",
         "League of Arab States"
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 "bi": {
   "name": "Burundi",
   "official_name": "Republic of Burundi",
   "topLevelDomain": [
     ".bi"
   ],
   "alpha2Code": "BI",
   "alpha3Code": "BDI",
   "cioc": "BDI",
   "numericCode": "108",
   "callingCode": "+257",
   "capital": "Gitega",
   "altSpellings": [
     "BI",
     "Republic of Burundi",
     "Republika y'Uburundi",
     "République du Burundi"
   ],
   "region": "Africa",
   "subregion": "Eastern Africa",
   "population": 11890781,
   "latLng": {
     "country": [
       -3.5,
       30
     ],
     "capital": [
       -3.43,
       29.93
     ]
   },
   "demonyms": {
     "eng": {
       "f": "Burundian",
       "m": "Burundian"
     },
     "fra": {
       "f": "Burundaise",
       "m": "Burundais"
     }
   },
   "area": 27834,
   "gini": {
     "2013": 38.6
   },
   "timezones": [
     "UTC+02:00"
   ],
   "borders": [
     "COD",
     "RWA",
     "TZA"
   ],
   "nativeNames": {
     "fra": {
       "official": "République du Burundi",
       "common": "Burundi"
     },
     "run": {
       "official": "Republika y'Uburundi ",
       "common": "Uburundi"
     }
   },
   "currencies": {
     "BIF": {
       "name": "Burundian franc",
       "symbol": "Fr"
     }
   },
   "languages": {
     "fra": "French",
     "run": "Kirundi"
   },
   "translations": {
     "ara": "بوروندي",
     "ces": "Burundi",
     "cym": "Bwrwndi",
     "deu": "Burundi",
     "est": "Burundi",
     "fin": "Burundi",
     "fra": "Burundi",
     "hrv": "Burundi",
     "hun": "Burundi",
     "ita": "Burundi",
     "jpn": "ブルンジ",
     "kor": "부룬디",
     "nld": "Burundi",
     "per": "بوروندی",
     "pol": "Burundi",
     "por": "Burundi",
     "rus": "Бурунди",
     "slk": "Burundi",
     "spa": "Burundi",
     "swe": "Burundi",
     "urd": "برونڈی",
     "zho": "布隆迪"
   },
   "flag": {
     "small": "https://flagcdn.com/24x18/bi.png",
     "medium": "https://flagcdn.com/96x72/bi.png",
     "large": "https://flagcdn.com/256x192/bi.png"
   },
   "regionalBlocs": [
     {
       "acronym": "AU",
       "name": "African Union",
       "otherNames": [
         "الاتحاد الأفريقي",
         "Union africaine",
         "União Africana",
         "Unión Africana",
         "Umoja wa Afrika"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are having different country codes as the key in response, we can access a list of those items like below

```
var decodedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
  List<String> keys = decodedJson.keys.toList();
  print(decodedJson[keys[0]]);
```

Create a class for the data of each country like follows

```
class CountryInfo {
  String? name;
  String? officialName;
  List<String>? topLevelDomain;
  String? alpha2Code;
  String? alpha3Code;
  String? cioc;
  String? numericCode;
  String? callingCode;
  String? capital;
  List<String>? altSpellings;
  String? region;
  String? subregion;
  int? population;
  LatLng? latLng;
  Demonyms? demonyms;
  int? area;
  String? gini;
  List<String>? timezones;
  List<String>? borders;
  NativeNames? nativeNames;
  Currencies? currencies;
  Languages? languages;
  Translations? translations;
  Flag? flag;
  List<RegionalBlocs>? regionalBlocs;

  CountryInfo(
      {this.name,
      this.officialName,
      this.topLevelDomain,
      this.alpha2Code,
      this.alpha3Code,
      this.cioc,
      this.numericCode,
      this.callingCode,
      this.capital,
      this.altSpellings,
      this.region,
      this.subregion,
      this.population,
      this.latLng,
      this.demonyms,
      this.area,
      this.gini,
      this.timezones,
      this.borders,
      this.nativeNames,
      this.currencies,
      this.languages,
      this.translations,
      this.flag,
      this.regionalBlocs});

  CountryInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    officialName = json['official_name'];
    topLevelDomain = json['topLevelDomain'].cast<String>();
    alpha2Code = json['alpha2Code'];
    alpha3Code = json['alpha3Code'];
    cioc = json['cioc'];
    numericCode = json['numericCode'];
    callingCode = json['callingCode'];
    capital = json['capital'];
    altSpellings = json['altSpellings'].cast<String>();
    region = json['region'];
    subregion = json['subregion'];
    population = json['population'];
    latLng =
        json['latLng'] != null ? new LatLng.fromJson(json['latLng']) : null;
    demonyms = json['demonyms'] != null
        ? new Demonyms.fromJson(json['demonyms'])
        : null;
    area = json['area'];
    gini = json['gini'];
    timezones = json['timezones'].cast<String>();
    borders = json['borders'].cast<String>();
    nativeNames = json['nativeNames'] != null
        ? new NativeNames.fromJson(json['nativeNames'])
        : null;
    currencies = json['currencies'] != null
        ? new Currencies.fromJson(json['currencies'])
        : null;
    languages = json['languages'] != null
        ? new Languages.fromJson(json['languages'])
        : null;
    translations = json['translations'] != null
        ? new Translations.fromJson(json['translations'])
        : null;
    flag = json['flag'] != null ? new Flag.fromJson(json['flag']) : null;
    if (json['regionalBlocs'] != null) {
      regionalBlocs = <RegionalBlocs>[];
      json['regionalBlocs'].forEach((v) {
        regionalBlocs!.add(new RegionalBlocs.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['official_name'] = this.officialName;
    data['topLevelDomain'] = this.topLevelDomain;
    data['alpha2Code'] = this.alpha2Code;
    data['alpha3Code'] = this.alpha3Code;
    data['cioc'] = this.cioc;
    data['numericCode'] = this.numericCode;
    data['callingCode'] = this.callingCode;
    data['capital'] = this.capital;
    data['altSpellings'] = this.altSpellings;
    data['region'] = this.region;
    data['subregion'] = this.subregion;
    data['population'] = this.population;
    if (this.latLng != null) {
      data['latLng'] = this.latLng!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.demonyms != null) {
      data['demonyms'] = this.demonyms!.toJson();
    }
    data['area'] = this.area;
    data['gini'] = this.gini;
    data['timezones'] = this.timezones;
    data['borders'] = this.borders;
    if (this.nativeNames != null) {
      data['nativeNames'] = this.nativeNames!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.currencies != null) {
      data['currencies'] = this.currencies!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.languages != null) {
      data['languages'] = this.languages!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.translations != null) {
      data['translations'] = this.translations!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.flag != null) {
      data['flag'] = this.flag!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.regionalBlocs != null) {
      data['regionalBlocs'] =
          this.regionalBlocs!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class LatLng {
  List<int>? country;
  List<double>? capital;

  LatLng({this.country, this.capital});

  LatLng.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['country'].cast<int>();
    capital = json['capital'].cast<double>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['capital'] = this.capital;
    return data;
  }
}

class Demonyms {
  Eng? eng;
  Eng? fra;

  Demonyms({this.eng, this.fra});

  Demonyms.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    eng = json['eng'] != null ? new Eng.fromJson(json['eng']) : null;
    fra = json['fra'] != null ? new Eng.fromJson(json['fra']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.eng != null) {
      data['eng'] = this.eng!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.fra != null) {
      data['fra'] = this.fra!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Eng {
  String? f;
  String? m;

  Eng({this.f, this.m});

  Eng.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    f = json['f'];
    m = json['m'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['f'] = this.f;
    data['m'] = this.m;
    return data;
  }
}

class NativeNames {
  Prs? prs;
  Prs? pus;
  Prs? tuk;

  NativeNames({this.prs, this.pus, this.tuk});

  NativeNames.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    prs = json['prs'] != null ? new Prs.fromJson(json['prs']) : null;
    pus = json['pus'] != null ? new Prs.fromJson(json['pus']) : null;
    tuk = json['tuk'] != null ? new Prs.fromJson(json['tuk']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.prs != null) {
      data['prs'] = this.prs!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.pus != null) {
      data['pus'] = this.pus!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.tuk != null) {
      data['tuk'] = this.tuk!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Prs {
  String? official;
  String? common;

  Prs({this.official, this.common});

  Prs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    official = json['official'];
    common = json['common'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['official'] = this.official;
    data['common'] = this.common;
    return data;
  }
}

class Currencies {
  AFN? aFN;

  Currencies({this.aFN});

  Currencies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    aFN = json['AFN'] != null ? new AFN.fromJson(json['AFN']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.aFN != null) {
      data['AFN'] = this.aFN!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class AFN {
  String? name;
  String? symbol;

  AFN({this.name, this.symbol});

  AFN.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    symbol = json['symbol'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['symbol'] = this.symbol;
    return data;
  }
}

class Languages {
  String? prs;
  String? pus;
  String? tuk;

  Languages({this.prs, this.pus, this.tuk});

  Languages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    prs = json['prs'];
    pus = json['pus'];
    tuk = json['tuk'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['prs'] = this.prs;
    data['pus'] = this.pus;
    data['tuk'] = this.tuk;
    return data;
  }
}

class Translations {
  String? ara;
  String? ces;
  String? cym;
  String? deu;
  String? est;
  String? fin;
  String? fra;
  String? hrv;
  String? hun;
  String? ita;
  String? jpn;
  String? kor;
  String? nld;
  String? per;
  String? pol;
  String? por;
  String? rus;
  String? slk;
  String? spa;
  String? swe;
  String? urd;
  String? zho;

  Translations(
      {this.ara,
      this.ces,
      this.cym,
      this.deu,
      this.est,
      this.fin,
      this.fra,
      this.hrv,
      this.hun,
      this.ita,
      this.jpn,
      this.kor,
      this.nld,
      this.per,
      this.pol,
      this.por,
      this.rus,
      this.slk,
      this.spa,
      this.swe,
      this.urd,
      this.zho});

  Translations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    ara = json['ara'];
    ces = json['ces'];
    cym = json['cym'];
    deu = json['deu'];
    est = json['est'];
    fin = json['fin'];
    fra = json['fra'];
    hrv = json['hrv'];
    hun = json['hun'];
    ita = json['ita'];
    jpn = json['jpn'];
    kor = json['kor'];
    nld = json['nld'];
    per = json['per'];
    pol = json['pol'];
    por = json['por'];
    rus = json['rus'];
    slk = json['slk'];
    spa = json['spa'];
    swe = json['swe'];
    urd = json['urd'];
    zho = json['zho'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['ara'] = this.ara;
    data['ces'] = this.ces;
    data['cym'] = this.cym;
    data['deu'] = this.deu;
    data['est'] = this.est;
    data['fin'] = this.fin;
    data['fra'] = this.fra;
    data['hrv'] = this.hrv;
    data['hun'] = this.hun;
    data['ita'] = this.ita;
    data['jpn'] = this.jpn;
    data['kor'] = this.kor;
    data['nld'] = this.nld;
    data['per'] = this.per;
    data['pol'] = this.pol;
    data['por'] = this.por;
    data['rus'] = this.rus;
    data['slk'] = this.slk;
    data['spa'] = this.spa;
    data['swe'] = this.swe;
    data['urd'] = this.urd;
    data['zho'] = this.zho;
    return data;
  }
}

class Flag {
  String? small;
  String? medium;
  String? large;

  Flag({this.small, this.medium, this.large});

  Flag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    small = json['small'];
    medium = json['medium'];
    large = json['large'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['small'] = this.small;
    data['medium'] = this.medium;
    data['large'] = this.large;
    return data;
  }
}

class RegionalBlocs {
  String? acronym;
  String? name;

  RegionalBlocs({this.acronym, this.name});

  RegionalBlocs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    acronym = json['acronym'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['acronym'] = this.acronym;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now you can convert each item with key list to this model like follows

```
 var decodedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
  List<String> keys = decodedJson.keys.toList();
  print(decodedJson[keys[0]]);
///Output
///{name: Afghanistan, official_name: Islamic Republic of Afghanistan, topLevelDomain: [.af], alpha2Code: AF, alpha3Code: AFG, cioc: AFG, numericCode: 004, callingCode: +93, capital: Kabul, altSpellings: [AF, Afġānistān], region: Asia, subregion: Southern Asia, population: 2837743, latLng: {country: [33, 65], capital: [34.52, 69.18]}, demonyms: {eng: {f: Afghan, m: Afghan}, fra: {f: Afghane, m: Afghan}}, area: 652230, gini: Not Available, timezones: [UTC+04:30], borders: [IRN, PAK, TKM, UZB, TJK, CHN], nativeNames: {prs: {official: جمهوری اسلامی افغانستان, common: افغانستان}, pus: {official: د افغانستان اسلامي جمهوریت, common: افغانستان}, tuk: {official: Owganystan Yslam Respublikasy, common: Owganystan}}, currencies: {AFN: {name: Afghan afghani, symbol: ؋}}, languages: {prs: Dari, pus: Pashto, tuk: Turkmen}, translations: {ara: أفغانستان, ces: Afghánistán, cym: Affganistan, deu: Afghanistan, est: Afganistan, fin: Afganistan, fra: Afghanistan, hrv: Afganistan, hun: Afganisztán, ita: Afghanistan, jpn: アフガニスタン, kor: 아프가니스탄, nld: Afghanistan, per: افغانستان, pol: Afganistan, por: Afeganistão, rus: Афганистан, slk: Afganistan, spa: Afganistán, swe: Afghanistan, urd: افغانستان, zho: 阿富汗}, flag: {small: https://flagcdn.com/24x18/af.png, medium: https://flagcdn.com/96x72/af.png, large: https://flagcdn.com/256x192/af.png}, regionalBlocs: [{acronym: SAARC, name: South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation}]}
///

  CountryInfo firstKeyInfo = CountryInfo.fromJson(decodedJson[keys[0]]);
  print(firstKeyInfo.name);
///output
///Afghanistan
```

[Dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=793392644fe2fb03c1a074fc09a88440) Example